# Transaction on CSV File in java

Tags: java

The following transaction file content is the CSV file that contains financial transactions, where each line is either a debit or a credit transaction on a specific account number.

> > 00001500205568600,D,1520.15
> >     00001500205568600,D,12500.00
> >     00001500205568600,C,44.00
> >     00001300220978215,C,59800.13
> >     00001300220978215,C,80000.00
> >     00001300220978215,C,15850.23
> >     00001300220978215,D,85.60
> >     00002200540006410,D,595550.03
> >     00002200540006410,C,1200.00
> >     00002200540006410,D,3250.00
> >     00001300220978215,C,12.55
> >     00009650025500020,C,290050.00
> >     00009650025500020,D,96.00

As you can see, each line has the following format: `<account number>,<D or C; D for debit and C for credit>,<amount>`.

The file contains transactions for multiple account numbers, but more than one for each account number.

Write a Java program that reads the transactions.txt file line by line and calculates the final balance of each account number.

Assume that each account will start with 0 balance, the amount of each debit (D) transaction will be subtracted from the balance and the amount of each credit (C) transaction will be added to the balance.

The program should print each account number with its final balance.

I have this code and I need help in making transaction and print them.

```
public class Test1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      test1 obj = new test1();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

    String csvFile = "transactions.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";



    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


            System.out.println("Account Number  " + country[0] 
                                 + " , Account Balance=" + country[2] + "]");

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't ask you to print out the transactions, it only asks you to print out the final balance.  I suggest you that first.

Comment: I Know that . I had put this print statement to make sure that the read process from CSV file is working well .

Comment: I need To Know How I can Count the final balance from this CSV file??

Comment: When column 1 is 'C' you add column 2 to the total, when it is 'd' you subtract column 2 from the total.

Comment: can you write the code please ?

Comment: You should be able to write an `if` condition. To turn the number into a double you can use `Double.parseDouble`

Answer (score 1):

You should try to structure a bit the program. Since you process *transactions*, you can create a class `Transaction` that shall hold one transaction properties.

```
public class Transaction {
   // ...
}
```

Initialise a `List<Transaction>` to hold all the transactions from the file.

```
List<Transaction> allTrans = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, process the file and for each line, create a new `Transaction` object, that you can put in the list:

```
allTrans.add(new Transaction(/*...params read from a line...*/));
```

Once you have this initialised, processing the list to compute the total for each account can be done easily with Java8 streams and collectors. Assuming you have `getAccount()` and `getAmount()` methods on the `Transaction` bean, and `getAmount()` returns a positive value for a credit and negative for a debit:

```
Map<String, Double> totals = trans.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getAccount, 
                         Collectors.summingDouble(Transaction::getAmount)));
```

Will give you a `Map` where the key is an account number and the value, the total of the transactions for this account.